# How to get an element by name and set its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

There should be a simple solution for this.  I need to get an input element by name and set its value.

The following Javascript does not work:

```
x = document.getElementsByName($('#questions').val());
x.value=this.value;
```

Is there a simple solution using JQuery?

Comment: document.getElementsByName(); won't be a single element ... . It's something like [element1, ...].

Comment: Why not set the input's id to be the same as it's name and use `$('#myInputsId').val('whatever')`

Comment: @MatthewJordan it seems that he wants to change the value of an element which name is the value of the element with the id questions. So your comment is wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Description

You are mixing normal javascript and jQuery.
Use the attribute selector.

Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/HasfR/)

#### Sample

**Html**

```
<input type="text" name="nameOfTheInputElement"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("input[name='nameOfTheInputElement']").val("your value");
});
​
```

### Edit

If you want, for some reason, change a element which name is a value in another element
then do this. [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/HasfR/3/)

**Html**

```
<input type="text" id="questions" value="nameOfTheInputElement"/>    
<input type="text" name="nameOfTheInputElement"/>
```

​**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    var name = $("#questions").val();
    $("input[name='"+name +"']").val("your value");
});​
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery - Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
- [jsFiddle Demonstration (first sample)](http://jsfiddle.net/HasfR/)
- [jsFiddle Demonstration (second sample)](http://jsfiddle.net/HasfR/3/)

Comment: By the looks of the question, the OP wants to specifcy the name of the element to get in a textbox of some kind

Comment: OP: "I need to get an input element by name and set its value". My code does the job, i don't under stand your comment, sorry.

Comment: @dknaack it seems that he wants to change the value of an element which name is the value of the element with the id questions. So your answer isn't the correct answer.

Comment: @BenniKa maybe that is what he want, my answer is extended. Thank you!!

Answer (score 6):

A simple, pure JavaScript (and therefore faster) solution:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName(document.getElementById('questions').value)[0].value = this.value;
```

I know jQuery's tagline is 'Write less, do more', and in many cases it is true... `many cases !== always`, though ;-)

Answer (score 3):

[getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) returns a node-list, so you need to get the first one `getElementsByName(...)[0]`

But you are already using jQuery, so use it. Read some tutorials about the [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var q = $("#question").val();
var x = $("input[name='" + q + "']").val();
```

on the 2nd line, variable q, the name provided in input with id 'question', will be enclosed with ' and could contain any supported characters, like space, :, -, etc

If you need the value of a component regardless of its tag, you can do this:

```
var x = $("[name='" + q + "']").val();
```

Consider that this approach `$("[name='" + q + "']")` can return more than one element, but `.val()` will return only the value of the first element.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to get an element by name, and the name of the element you're selecting will be specified by some dropdown or text area.

Here's my take on it:

**Html**

```
<input type="text" id="enteredName">
<button id="doTheStuff">Do the work</button>

<input name="one" value="One">
<input name="two" value="Two">
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#doTheStuff').click(function(){
    var objectOfInterest = $('[name=\'' + $('#enteredName').val() + '\']');
    alert(objectOfInterest.val());
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gwvxu/)

Here's [another working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gwvxu/1/) using a dropdown to specify the selection name.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form-id input[name="name-input"]').val('your value');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.